# How to convert 'double' to 'string' in user-friendly form

Tags: c++, string, double

i have the following problem:
customer want to present `double` type to a `string` by an optimal way. it need to be converted to string and showed on a form(sms, table and other).

```
100000000.949999 needs to be converted in 100000000.950;
10.000000001 -> 10.0;
100000000000000.19292 -> 1e+14;
1000.123456789 -> 1000.123;
0.00001 -> 0.0;
```

The code for converting is a performance critical, it means that no `std::stringstream` + `setprecision()` should be used.

It will be great to implement params 'precision' as argument of my `toStringNew()` function, but this improvements may critically affects all our system, and we are planning implement it in the next release.
But this problem is actual now.
I wrote the following code:

```
inline bool toStringNew(std::string& str, double const& value)
{
    static const char *zero_double_str = "0.0";
    static const double zero_double_limit = 0.001;
    static const int max_double_prec_symbol = 13;
    static const int max_fract_num = 3;
    static const int max_fract_mul = pow(10, max_fract_num);
    str.clear();
    //get digits of integer part
    double fabs_value = fabs(value);
    int64_t len = log10(fabs_value);
    //Round 2 zero
    if(len <= 0) //it means that only fraction part is present
    {
        if(fabs_value < zero_double_limit)
        {
            str = zero_double_str;
            return true;
        }
        //use default
        return boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), value);
    }
    else if(len > max_double_prec_symbol)   //default
    {
        return boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), value);
    }
    //cast to integer
    int64_t i = static_cast<int64_t>(value);
    //cast fract to integer
    int64_t fract_i = static_cast<int64_t>(round((value - i)* max_fract_mul));
    //reserve string memory
    size_t str_len = len + 1 +  max_fract_num + (value > 0 ? 0 : 1) + 1; 
    str.reserve(str_len);
    //convert integer
    boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), i);
    str+='.';
    //convert fract
    if(fract_i > 0)
    {
        str+='.';
        int64_t fract_i_len = log10(fract_i);
        //fill zero before: 0.001 -> 1 -> 001
        while(++fract_i_len < max_fract_num)
        {
            str += '0';
        }
        //remove zero after: 010 -> 01
        while(!(fract_i % 10))
        {
            fract_i = fract_i / 10;
        }
        boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), fract_i);
    }
    boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(str), fract_i);
    return true;
}
```

This works at 1,5 times faster than `boost::spirit::karma::generate()` for `double` type.

Can you give me some advices how to satisfy my customer?

Comment: Have you tried measuring how slow `stringstream` is? My guess it, that it is faster than you expect.

Comment: what about `std::to_string`?

Comment: i tried using sstream and got the following results:
    `New ToString() TPS = 2257627.5000000000`
    `SStream ToString() TPS = 503520.9375000000`
    `old ToString() TPS = 1871579.8750000000`

std::stringstream is too slowly

Comment: @DavidHaim
it is too hardly to set up this project on c++11

Answer (score 9):

I would look at the [C++ String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html).  I have used it for parsing and number conversion and it has shown to be very fast.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <strtk.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
   double pi = M_PI;
   std::cout << strtk::type_to_string<double>( pi ) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is critical maybe use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/). It will be better than your home grown solution and also I think it will perform better. Using the `*` format specifier you can also make the precision an argument.

Comment: `New ToString()`  
`TPS = 4086582.7500000000`  
`SStream ToString()`  
`TPS = 518112.9062500000`  
`Sprintf ToString()`  
`TPS = 1592562.3750000000`  
`old ToString()`  
`TPS = 2909644.5000000000`  

`snprintf` is the more slowly. It need performance at least as `old ToString`